# python json.dump creates too big a file

Tags: python, json, csv

So I have this csv file of size 380 MB or so. I created an empty data structure as this one:
{ ID1 { day1 : [ [flow,hour1],[flow, hour2] ...[flow, hour23]], day2: [...]...day30:[...]}, ID2...}. I extract from the csv and filled this structure with the loop below, which takes about 3 minutes. there are about 2000 IDs, each 30 days, each 24 hours. Then when I try to dump this filled structure in a json file, it took hours and the output file's size exceeded 3 GBs before i quit the script. Since JSON is supposed to be more compact, is this supposed to happen? because I tried with smaller scales (1000 entries) and it worked well. Is there a good way to deal with this? Thank you.

NOTE: 'stations' is a list of stations that row['ID'] should match too.

```
import csv
import json, pprint, datetime, time



meta_f = open( metadata_path , 'rb' )
meta_read = csv.DictReader(meta_f,delimiter='\t')


hour_f = open(hourly_path,'r')
hour_read = csv.DictReader(hour_f, delimiter=',')



stations = []
no_coords = []
for i,row in enumerate(meta_read):    
    if not row['Longitude'] or not row['Latitude']:
        no_coords.append(row['ID'])                
    elif in_box(row,bound):
        stations.append(row['ID'])

data={} 
number_of_days=30
days={}
for i in range(1,number_of_days+1):
    days[i]=[]    
for station in stations:
    data[int(station)]=days 


with open('E:/pythonxy/Projects/UP/json_data.txt','wb') as f:
    json.dump({},f)
    f.close()
with open('E:/pythonxy/Projects/UP/json_data.txt','rb') as f:
    d=json.load(f)    

#i=0
t0=time.time()    
for row in hour_read:
    #if i>1000:
        #break
    if row['Station'] in stations:
        #print row['Station']         
        t=datetime.datetime.strptime(row['TimeStamp'], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
        data[int(row['Station'])][int(t.day)]+=[[row['TotalFlow'],t.hour]]
    #i+=1
    #print i
d.update(data)
print time.time()-t0

t0=time.time()
with open('E:/pythonxy/Projects/UP/json_data.txt','wb') as f:
    json.dump(d,f)
    f.close()
print time.time()-t0    

print 'DONE'
```

Comment: Some of this makes no sense. You dump an empty dict to a file, only to then load the dict back from the file, fill it with contents, and then dump it back again?

Comment: you are doing something wrong theres no way a 380mb csv would become more than 3gb when dumped to json ... I couldnt tell you what your doing wrong but certainly something

Comment: i meant to create a json format first so i can dump into it later; if there is a better way please let me know; i know nothing.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I know, and I cannot know what it is. Thus my question.

Comment: @JoranBeasley - Are you certain?  A JSON structure is going to include keys (columns) for every value of every row.  Depending on how many rows, it's possible that the overhead from column repetition could be excessive.

Comment: put a sample of the 380 mb csv online and provide a link. @g.d.d.c yeah but then I still say he is doing something wrong and needs to work on his data structure ...

Comment: You don't need to do anything special to prepare the file for dumping.

Comment: @JoranBeasley - Yes, but it may not be a wrong _approach_ as much as a wrong _solution_.  It might be that he shouldn't be trying to do what he's doing because the data he has is not well suited to the output format he's trying to convert it to.

Comment: @g.d.d.c yup no disagreement there ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Here is the csv input
https://www.dropbox.com/s/b5c8cjky8bvk54u/d07_text_station_hour_2014_041.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for station in stations:
    data[int(station)]=days
```

Every entry you create in `data` with this loop refers to the same dict as a value. That means every time you add something to any `data[something]` dict, you add it to all of them. The result when you dump it to a file is wrong and huge. To avoid this, you can deep copy the `days` dict:

```
from copy import deepcopy
for station in stations:
    data[int(station)] = deepcopy(days)
```

Comment: `days` is an empty dict, just replace it with `data[int(station)] = {}`. But it *is* the reason the JSON ends up with loads of duplicated data.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: No, `days` is filled with lists in the loop immediately above this one.

Comment: Ah, indeed. It can be replaced with `{i + 1: [] for i in range(31)}`. But only if the OP insists on using a dictionary there, as a list would be more efficient (`[[] for _ in range(32)]` and ignore index 0).

Comment: @user2357112 but thats even sillier because then you have potentially unused keys... it would be better if it were a 2d array `[[],[],...,[]]`

Comment: @user2357112 Here is a thesis, CREATING the data structure and filling it all takes 3 minutes, but DUMPING it takes forever, and this is counter intuitive, because there is no way python can allocate 3 gb of memory to a dict structure; so something is wrong in the json.dumping process, and not in the loop

Comment: @user3761534: All `days[something]` entries refer to the same huge dict; they don't all take separate memory. When you dump it to a JSON file, each entry needs to be dumped separately, so they *do* take up separate space on disk.

Comment: Yup you are absolutely right! Thanks; I deepcopy-ed it and the dumping took 85 seconds and 17 MB. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer per se, but JSON is actually much less compact than CSV. Take this example.

CSV:

```
X,Y,Z
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

JSON:

```
[{X:1,Y:2,Z:3},{X:4,Y:5,Z:6}]
```

That's 17 bytes for CSV and 29 for JSON!

Comment: definately a true story howver it could also be represented as `{cols:[x,y,z],values:[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]}` as such I feel there is something more here

Comment: @JoranBeasley Even then that's an extra 2 bytes per item `[` and `],` vs `\n`

Comment: still would not acount for a size increase of the size the OP talks about ... (none the less I +1'd this answer since you are definitely right)